# howto make svn diff look like diff?

Tags: svn, diff

There's another question: howto make diff look like svn diff? but I want the exact opposite.
I'm trying to get svn diff to display with < and >

The obvious answer would be:

```
svn diff --diff-cmd /usr/bin/diff  file
```

but when I do that I get

```
/usr/bin/diff: illegal option -- L
```

So I do this

```
svn diff --diff-cmd /usr/bin/echo  file
```

to see what's going on. and it spits out all this, which I can see why diff doesn't like it....

```
-u -L file (revision 11371) -L file   (working copy) .svn/text-base/file.svn-base file
```

So... how do I make svn actually use another program for diffing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have a version of `diff` installed on your system that is too old or incompatible with how svn wants to call it. In my system, the -L option is defined thusly:

```
   -L label
   --label=label
          Use label instead of the file name in the context format and unified format headers.
```

So you should just use a diff command that removes that flag before passing it along to your system's diff.  I do something similar to add a custom set of options to diff (and add colours), in my `.subversion/configs` file:

```
diff-cmd=/home/ether/bin/svndiff-w
```

...where the program is just a simple shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
diff=/usr/bin/colordiff
args="-u -wi -U 6 --new-file"    
exec ${diff} ${args} "$@"
```

This is discussed in more detail in the manual under [Using External Differencing and Merge Tools](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.advanced.externaldifftools.html).

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error with the `--diff-cmd` option, this is how I could force correct usage of my `/usr/bin/diff`:

```
svn cat $FILE --revision COMMITTED | diff $FILE -
```